# image onclick in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onclick

I'm trying to add onClick function every time the user press the img.
I tried some options that I found here at stack overflow.
none of the above options works for me.
I share some options that didn't work:

```
import React from "react";


export default function Movie(props) {
  
  const imageClick = () => {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
  }  
    return <img alt = "movieposter" src = {props.link} className ="d-flex justify-content-start m-3" id="movie" onClick={() => imageClick}/>
  }
```

```
import React from "react";


export default function Movie(props) {
  
  imageClick = () => {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
  }  
    return <img alt = "movieposter" src = {props.link} className ="d-flex justify-content-start m-3" id="movie" onClick={this.imageClick}/>
  }
```

```
import React from "react";


export default function Movie(props) {
  
  imageClick = () => {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
  }

  render () 
    {
    return (
    <img alt = "movieposter" src = {props.link} className ="d-flex justify-content-start m-3" id="movie" onClick={this.imageClick}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to first read and understand about the basics of `this` keyword in react. Try this article https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";

export default function Movie(props) {  
  const imageClick = () => {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
  }  
  return <img alt = "movieposter" src = {props.link} className ="d-flex 
    justify-content-start m-3" id="movie" onClick={() => imageClick()}/>
 }
```

You are not invoking the function in the first example.

Functional component in React are stateless(instance less). So, they don't have access to this keyword. Therefore, the second and third example won't work. Simply, use the above example.

Comment: He is using `this` in a functional component, in the other two examples, you cannot solve it by binding.

Comment: Thank you @VishnuSajeev for correcting. Functional component in React are stateless(instance less). So, they don't have access to this keyword. Therefore, the second and third example won't work. Simply, use the first example

Answer (score 0):

if you need to call func in an arrow function

```
import React from "react";

export default function Movie(props) {  
  const imageClick = () => {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
  }  
      return <img alt = "movieposter" src = {props.link} className ="d-flex 
    justify-content-start m-3" id="movie" onClick={() => imageClick()}/>
 }
```

or if you want to pass you handler simply

```
import React from "react";

export default function Movie(props) {  
  const imageClick = () => {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
  }  
      return <img alt = "movieposter" src = {props.link} className ="d-flex 
    justify-content-start m-3" id="movie" onClick={imageClick}/>
 }
```

or if you use class base components

```
import React from "react";

class Movie extends React.Component {
  imageClick() {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
  }  
      return <img alt = "movieposter" src = {props.link} className ="d-flex 
    justify-content-start m-3" id="movie" onClick={this.imageClick}/>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For your function:

```
function imageClick () {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
}
```

and function call part:

```
<img alt = "movieposter" src = {props.link} className ="d-flex 
        justify-content-start m-3" id="movie" onClick={imageClick} />
```